# Cant run Python Views on Couchdb

Tags: python, django, couchdb

i started using couchdb with python-couchdb recently. The problem is when i use futon run my views written in python i get the following error message:

Error: os_process_error

{exit_status,1}

even for the default view it crashes.

```
def fun(doc):
  yield None, doc
```

i haven't yet found much information regarding this issue so at this point im really lost. This is the log i get from couchdb:

```
{<0.3907.0>,crash_report,
 [[{initial_call,{couch_file,init,['Argument__1']}},
   {pid,<0.3907.0>},
   {registered_name,[]},
   {error_info,
       {exit,
           {os_process_error,{exit_status,1}},
           [{gen_server,terminate,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
   {ancestors,
       [<0.3906.0>,couch_view,couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,
        <0.33.0>]},
   {messages,[]},
   {links,[#Port<0.1483>,<0.3910.0>]},
   {dictionary,[]},
   {trap_exit,true},
   {status,running},
   {heap_size,377},
   {stack_size,24},
   {reductions,1423}],
  [{neighbour,
       [{pid,<0.3910.0>},
        {registered_name,[]},
        {initial_call,{couch_ref_counter,init,['Argument__1']}},
        {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
        {ancestors,
            [<0.3906.0>,couch_view,couch_secondary_services,
             couch_server_sup,<0.33.0>]},
   {messages,[]},
   {links,[#Port<0.1483>,<0.3910.0>]},
   {dictionary,[]},
   {trap_exit,true},
   {status,running},
   {heap_size,377},
   {stack_size,24},
   {reductions,1423}],
  [{neighbour,
       [{pid,<0.3910.0>},
        {registered_name,[]},
        {initial_call,{couch_ref_counter,init,['Argument__1']}},
        {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
        {ancestors,
            [<0.3906.0>,couch_view,couch_secondary_services,
             couch_server_sup,<0.33.0>]},
        {messages,
            [{'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.0.16475>,process,<0.3906.0>,
                 {os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}}]},
        {links,[<0.3907.0>]},
        {dictionary,[]},
        {trap_exit,false},
        {status,runnable},
        {heap_size,233},
        {stack_size,9},
        {reductions,47}]}]]}}
```

Im running this on Ubuntu 10.04, with Django, couchdb and python-couchdb. The views on javascript works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For couchdb-python query server exit status 1 means some error that.

1. What version of couchdb/couchdb-python you're uses?
2. Whats output will be if you run couchpy (or /usr/local/bin/couchpy or whatever you have setted in query_servers section for python key) directly from command line? Example as it should be:

$

```
~ $ couchpy
["reset"]
true
["add_fun", "def fun(doc): yield None, None"]
true
["map_doc", {}]
[[[null, null]]]
```

If p.2 works fine, try to enable CouchDB debug log level to trace query server commands and notice when it falls. If you're sure that this is a python query server bug, please write some [story](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/issues) about it. Thanks(:

P.S. I hope that you have [setup](http://packages.python.org/CouchDB/views.html) python query server correctly, but double things check never was useless(;

Comment: Hi, i was having issues with character enconding, that being solved did it. Thanks!